# Can text in UILabel have a colorWithPatternImage: assigned to it?

Tags: iphone, image, iphone-sdk-3.0

If so, can the image be animated?

Is there a good reason not to do this? Memory usage, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a label can have a pattern color.

[alt text http://img178.imageshack.us/img178/1995/textwithpatterncolor.png](http://img178.imageshack.us/img178/1995/textwithpatterncolor.png)

```
// make a UIColor with an image as the pattern
UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hot_grad_64px.png"];
UIColor *patternColorTile = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:tileImage];

// assign it to the .textColor property of a UILabel
self.testLabel.textColor = patternColorTile;

// the pattern will only align if both the .frame property of the 
// label AND the font size is the same as the image tile height
```

The pattern can be animated by switching between multiple pattern colors. I have flipped between a pattern image and a plain color at > 30fps and the iPhone device kept up fine.

As long as the image tile is small, I don't see any reason not to do this, but I haven't extensively profiled it.

Comment: As the font size gets bigger this fill color gets stretched and scaled funny, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @PsychoDad just resize the texture image.