# How to use colorWithPatternImage: with UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a `UILabel` with customized text that shows the current score of a game. The customer has given me screen shots where they would like the color/pattern of the text to be like that of a wooden panel, so it looks to be brownish with darker swirls within it.

Is this even possible? I have spent an enormous amount of time scouring the web for something related to this and have found nothing concrete. One lead I followed that didn't pan out was using:

```
[UILabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"WoodenPanel.png"]]];
```

It seems like there's a way to use an image and set it as the color for the text. But what results when I use this is a completely black `UILabel`. Is this on the right  track? Or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
[labelName setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGENAME.PNG"]]];
```

**NOT** like you did:

```
[UILabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGENAME.PNG"]]];
```

You have to put the name of the declared label instead of `UILabel`

Answer (score 0):

[Can text in UILabel have a colorWithPatternImage: assigned to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025304/can-text-in-uilabel-have-a-colorwithpatternimage-assigned-to-it)

It does use the colorWithPatternImage though

What do you mean by it didn't pan out.

Also this is a possible duplicate of the link I just gave you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I think part of the issue for why the UILabel turns black is that part of the image is black and so the UILabel is revealing only a portion of the image. I will continue to work on this and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had actually implemented it correctly. The line of code I provided above was not an exact line out of my program, but more of a generality.

The reason I was getting a completely black font was that part of the particular image I was using was entirely black. It seems that the image isn't scaled down to fit the text and UILabel so what was being revealed was the bottom 1/5 of the image. I did not have to solve this problem as the image provided for me to implement this was a repetitive pattern throughout the image so that any part of the image would produce the desired effect of a wooden panel type color font.